# Selecting past events up to current hour

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains events data. I also have a list of dates that I need to check through. So I loop though the given dates and query my table. I need to select the events that we on a given date and if the date is the same as today, I only need events that took place before certain time. The time is stored in a military format, like 14:30.

I think I've overcomplicated my query logic:

```
$current_date = date('Y-m-d');
$current_time = date('H:i');
```

The reason I use PHP time and date, because I can have an accurate time from a server I control. MySQL time is off by a few hours...

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE org.id = ".$ID."
AND (
         (
           DATE(events.date) = '".$givenDate."'
           AND
           '".$givenDate."' < '".$current_date."'
         )
         OR
         (
           DATE(events.date) = '".$givenDate."'
           AND
           '".$givenDate."' < '".$current_date."'
           AND
           events.time < '".$current_time."'
          )
     )
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue you are facing?

Comment: I am not selecting all results that should be selected. For example, the dates that are before today aren't picked up...

Comment: what is format of  `$givenDate` ?

Comment: why do you compare `$givenDate."' < '".$current_date` in sql but in php?

Comment: Best thing would be echo your query and show us the final query which is running.

Comment: The same as current date 2015-08-04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE org.id = ".$ID."
  AND date(events.date) = '".$givenDate."'
  and if ('".$givenDate."' = '".$current_date."', 
           events.time < '".$current_time."', true)
```